# Customize WooCommerce Error Message

Tags: filters, plugins, errors

I would like to change the wording of an error message I see in WooCommerce.

Are there any filters I can use to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with the `woocommerce_add_error` filter. Add the following to your functions.php file.

```
// alter the subscriptions error
function my_woocommerce_add_error( $error ) {
    if( 'The generic error message' == $error ) {
        $error = 'The shiny brand new error message';
    }
    return $error;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'my_woocommerce_add_error' );
```